# Facebook action and object submission

Tags: php, facebook, blackberry

I'm new to Facebook sdk and I want to use it in my project (blackberry app) 
has the developer I tried writing to my timeline with the code below through a web service and I was able to write to my timeline, my question is this: must I create an action and object that must be submitted for approval before other users can use my app to write to their timeline? Because permission is not granted when users try to write to their timeline.

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',array('link' => 'www.****.com','message' => $user_profile["name"].' just downloaded W1'));
    echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, if all you want to do is simply publish a post. However, your users will need to authenticate the app in order to post to their timeline. If you have registered an app already (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)), you will need to add the `publish_actions` permission to your app.

See [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) for more details.